# What is the difference between ContentResolver and LoaderManager?

Tags: android

I don't understand difference between `ContentResolver` and `LoaderManager`.

Comment: Both are completely different. did you read the docs? not much else we can tell you besides what the docs say

Answer (score 2):

Thery are different, i dont know why you compare, maybe we need to know the context.

ContentResolver resolves a URI to a specific Content provider.

LoaderManager helps an application manage longer-running operations in conjunction with the Activity or Fragment lifecycle

Answer (score 2):

`ContentResolver` is the layer between your application and other applications's `ContentProviders` (and maybe your own `ContentProviders`). You use them by calling `ContentResolver.query()`. However, since queries could take a while, you need to make the call on a separate thread, which you can either do by yourself, with an `AsyncTask` or something else, or you can use a `CursorLoader`, which is managed by the `LoaderManager` class.

From http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html:

> For the sake of clarity, the code snippets in this section call ContentResolver.query() on the "UI thread"". In actual code, however, you should do queries asynchronously on a separate thread. One way to do this is to use the CursorLoader class, which is described in more detail in the Loaders guide.

That's the connection between the two.